# Iphone darkens div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, mobile-safari

When you have a div with a click handler attached, the iphone darkens the div as a click indicator, when the div is clicked.

Example: view on mobile safari
http://jsbin.com/awejo3/4

My question is, how do I turn this behavior off? This is probably useful for most iphone users, but in some types of rich media applications, this is bad.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the "tap hightlight color" to transparent in css.

```
html
{
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;
}
```