# iphone- Highlighting div on tap that isn't a link

Tags: iphone, touch, highlight, tap

I'd like to highlight an entire div when the user touches or selects the text contained in the div.  I'm able to highlight the text only when it is contained in a span with a javascript function, but when I try to apply the function to the entire div it does not work.  In my research I've seen many people remove a highlight with -webkit-tap-highlight-color:, is there a way to use this or another css style to add a highlight to an item that is not a link?

The script I am using:

function changeColor(e,color){
   element = e;
   oldColor = element.currentStyle.background;
   element.style.background = color;
   }

Answer (score 1):

If you attach a click handler to the div Safari would highlight the div on click.

An Example is here http://jsbin.com/awejo3/4

Got the information from this question: [Iphone darkens div on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355154)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue on a mobile app and I have resolved issues with the below code.

```
*:not(a) {
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```